# Programmatically add/edit exchange2010 account

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

You have to know this is the first time I am working with exchange. I have to create a program to add/edit account on exchange 2010. I know there's a lot of answer about this topic on the internet, but I did not find any recent complete tutorial that explain how to do it from scratch (all the complete step).

I want to create a c# OR vb (.NET) program (window's client, or web, or whatever) with this functionality :

1. Add a new exchange 2010 email account
2. List existing account
3. Edit existing account

I know it may look simple for a lot of you, and I know there's a lot of good tutorial out there. But like I said, I am completely new to exchange, and all these tutorial look really complex to me.

I am asking you suggestion , tutorial, tips, something that can help me to understand. And I hope this question will help a lot of newb like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange Web Services (EWS) SDK does not support this feature.

Your best option is to use Power-Shell cmdlet. You can invoke it via C#.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff381465.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I ill take a look at this, but what about editing ? It look like Power-Shell cmdlet do not support editing ?

Comment: http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/dd575549.aspx there is Set-Mailbox cmdlet to Change the settings of an existing mailbox.