# How to create new mail account Microsoft Exchange 2013 EWS?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, exchange-server-2007

I want to create new mail account programmatically using Exchange web services. In 2010 it's not supported. We are going to work on 2013 Exchange.

Reference:

[Programmatically add/edit exchange2010 account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344138/programmatically-add-edit-exchange2010-account)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this using EWS (not powershell)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EWS doesn't have the ability to create mailboxes. In order to create mailboxes, you need to use the Exchange Management Shell's [New-Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997663(v=exchg.150).aspx) cmdlet.

**EDIT**

You can invoke cmdlets from C#. See [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj943721(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: but is it possible to call cmdlet from c#? i want to create a portal from where clients can create new mailboxes themselves?

Comment: There has to be a way to do this without invoking PowerShell commands. That's ridiculous.

Comment: @Jason Johnston: Agree with Drew Chapin. This is ridiculous, and certainly not a useful answer. Also, I don't need to invoke it from C#, I need to invoke it from another server than the exchange server with C#...